# Internal Network(Client-router-Server) of Linux(VirtualBox)

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox

I am trying to run a internal network that I built with three Linux Mint machines in VirtualBox. One acts as a client, the second one as a router and finally the server.

They are connected to my computer directly via NAT with an IP address of 10.0.2.15, they all have access to internet.

Then, the internal network is:

Client:
enp0s8:192.168.1.11
enp0s3:10.0.2.15

Router:
enp0s8:192.168.1.1
enp0s3:10.0.2.15
enps09:192.168.2.2

Server:
enp0s8:192.168.2.22
enp0s3:10.0.2.15

Facts:

- I have enabled packed forward in the router configuration( /etc/sysctl.conf)
- I can ping between client and server.
- I can do ssh between client-router and router-server.

Question:

Why I cannot ssh between client and server? All the time I try the output is "Connection timed out"

Hope this helps to understand the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: enable debugging and see what's going on `ssh -v remoteUser@remoteHost`

Answer (score 0):

debug1: reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying option for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.2.22" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.22 [192.168.2.22] port 22.

Then ... Timed out Connection